# How to sum times with different format cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have first cell with format `dd.h:mm` and second cell with format `h:mm:ss`. I tried to sum these 2 cells, but I get `#VALUE!`

How to sum these 2 cells and receive resulting cell with format `dd.h:mm`?

**Edited:**

Perhaps I don't know how to format cells as dates/times, because I just selected the custom format of the cells and typed the following 14.09:32 for 1st cell and 0:01:35 for the 2nd one.
How to format cells as times?

Comment: and what do you wanna do with seconds??

Comment: What exactly do these represent? Are they numeric fields formatted as dates/times? Or strings?

Comment: In future I want to sum more then 2 cells. And if I sum 2 cells with following milliseconds: 567+786 then seconds will be changed too ;)

Comment: @mbratch I selected the custom format of the cells and just typed the following 14.09:32 for 1st cell and 0:01:35 for the 2nd one. Perhaps I don't know how to format cells as dates/times...

Comment: Is it always one cell with a day/hours/minutes/etc and then all the rest will be a time? So you're wanting to compute some amount of time in the future past the given day/date?

Comment: @mbratch Yes, you're right.

Comment: If your Date is set using standard Excel date formatting (an integer representing a date) and your Time is set using the standard Excel time formatting (a value from `0` to `0.99988426` representing the time internally), then you can just add them. If you add multiple times cells to a date cell, Excel will "do the right thing" and give you the date corresponding to the first date plus those specific time intervals. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

You must first understand that Excel stores date and time as a numeric value representing the number of DAYS from 1/1/1900. For example, if you set the format of a cell to dd.hh:mm as you suggest, then type in the number 42 you will get 11.0:00. If you look at date that it converts to to in the formula bar you will see 2/11/1900 12:00:00 AM because this is 42 days from 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM. Hence the result based on your format: 11.0:00 (11th day and 0 zero hours and minutes).

When you type in 14.09:32 excel does not recognize this a numeric value and therefore stores this as text. You cannot add two texts fields together arithmetically, that is why you are getting #VALUE!.

When it comes to hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds these can be represented by everything after the decimal point in a date value. For example: `1 + (1 / 24)` equals 1/1/1900 01:00: AM. Since 1 equals exactly one day then `1 / 24` equals exactly 1 hour.

So, if you want to add, let's say 560 milliseconds to a date value, let's say A1 has a date value, you would do it like this:
`=A1+(560 * (1 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))` ... since there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, 60 seconds in an minute, 60 minutes in an hour, and 24 hours in a day.

To see milliseconds in your date you can create a custom format like this:
`h:mm:ss.000`

The `.000` part tells excel to display the milliseconds.

In conclusion, the format of the date has nothing to do with how it is stored - it only tells excel how to display the date. The bottom line is that if you remember that a date value is simply a number representing the number of days since 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM you should be able to do your addition.

If you expand on exactly what you're trying to do perhaps I can help you further.

Cheers,

Z